# Linux Server: Restore backup files in new directory

Tags: linux, restore

Linux Server: How can I copy overlapping files from backup folder with subfolder (directory) with all subfolders and files to newer folder(directory) withhout touching newer pre-existing files. Want only override overlapping files.

Comment: System administration questions don't belong on SO.

Comment: `rsync` should be able to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just use RSYNC. You can find examples here:
http://www.tecmint.com/rsync-local-remote-file-synchronization-commands/